# Resharper 6 simply ignores all my tests

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, resharper, resharper-6.0

I have a solution with a lot of nunit tests in different projects. When I run resharpers testrunner, it finds all the tests. But when it comes to execution it simply marks them all as grey and silently completes.

How do I figure out whats wrong with the testrunner, and most importantly how do I get it to run my tests.

I have resharper 6 in visual studio 2008. My code is on a fileshare, and everything runs in a virtual machine.

Comment: Have you tried to run any single test and see whether it runs well?

Comment: Yeah, the runner doesn't run any tests at all. They are all Grey and I get no feedback what so ever.

Comment: Does the error persist if you move your solution from file share to local drive?
There should be better error message anyway.

Comment: Can you share a code of any test fixture/class with any single test?

Comment: it works fine when the tests are located on the local harddrive. I've created an issue at JetBrains regarding the issue with full details. Seems it's related to the networkshare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetbrains has confirmed this to be a bug. That resharper wont run nunit tests located on a networkshare. They'll try to fix it in 6.1.

You can find the ticket here:
http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-275538

Comment: Just some info: I had the same problem but my solution was: I had an # in the path of the project